# Notification email when someone SSH Linux Centos7 workstation (output of the command who)

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, email, notifications

My Linux workstation is part of a shared Network. I would like to receive a notification email every time someone SSH my workstation. For that purpose, I opened the file `~/.bash_profile` in `gedit` (my `~/.bash_profile` file is completely empty) and I wrote the following lines:

```
IP="$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')"
HOST=$(hostname)
TIME_DATE_STAMP=$(date +"%e %b %Y, %a %r")

echo 'The '$IP' logged into '$HOST' on '$ TIME_DATE_STAMP'.' | mail -s 'SSH 
Login Notification' MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

I still don't get a notification email! Please notify me what I am doing wrong?

To get around this issue: 
When I use the command `"who -H"` int terminal. It  pulls out a list for all the incoming ssh actions to my workstation. My questions is: How the command "who" generate this information? what is the source of its data, so I can rely on it to get the `ssh` data that I want?

Comment: You have edited your own ~/.bash_profile, which is only executed when *you* log in; it has no effect on other users! (Commenting as to your attempted direction, as it's not an answer to the possible question of sending an actual notification email for those circumstances)

Comment: Thank you  so much Jeff! In this case should I make the code a bash and scheduale it to run periodically (i.e. using crontab -e)?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

- *Your* `~/.bash_profile` is only kicked off when *you* login. These other users may not be logging in as you.
- For observing who is logging into your CentOS machine over ssh, parse the output of `/var/log/secure`.

It'd look something like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/secure | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"logged in"* ]] && mail -s 'SSH Notification' $MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
done
```

EDIT: You've edited your question to ask about how the `who` command works. Look I'm not a C developer but [here's the source code of the `who` command](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/who.c") if you really want a peek at how it works. I don't think this is what you're looking for, however - and I know've no other way to assist you. Even if you could create a script to check if someone is logged in leveraging `cron` & `who`, there's always a possibility that someone could login & logout between your runs. Logs are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Rakaim. Nice solution, but I don't have permissions to read "var/log/secure"!

Comment: @goro Then you do not have the ability to see ssh sessions into your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the information you want from the command "who", then pipe it to the command mail. An example command:

```
 who | awk '{print $1" "$3" "$4" " $5}' | tail -1 | mail -s 'WARNING: SSH Notification' EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Save the previous command as a `bash`, and schedule it in `crontab` to run every specific minutes (e.g. every 30 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe the output of the command `last` .

```
last | head -1 | mail -s 'WARNING:' EMAIL_ADRESS
```